# How to make the method name in the class dynamic?

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to make the method name in the class dynamic when I create a object from the class I want to execute the method name dynamically bellow is my code .

```
public static void ExecuteTest() throws Exception 
{
    for (int i = 1,  j = 1;  i < 2;  i = i+1, j = j+1)  {    
            FW_ReadExcelFile N = new FW_ReadExcelFile();
            FW_ReadExcelFile.setExcelSheetEnvValues(i,i);
             //java.lang.String Flag2 = N.getTCExecuteFlag() ;

             String Flag = "YES";
             String Flag21 = N.getTCExecuteFlag();


            if ( Flag.equals(Flag21)  ){
                String TCName = N.getTCName();
                FW_Report u = new FW_Report();
                u.TCName; // the FW_Report  class has many methods and I want to call the method on my demand .
            }
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this??

Comment: Your code style indicates that you're new enough to Java that you *really* shouldn't be attempting reflection yet.

Comment: i want to execute  the method which is had a "YES" in a local excel sheet and those who had "NO" they shall be ignored .

Comment: A method can't has a "YES" in a local sheet, a method is a piece of code which works on variables.

Comment: thank you Xabster it is working fine now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i want to execute the method name dynamically

Use [Reflections in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful) to achieve this.

Sample code:

```
        Class<?> name = Class.forName("ClassName");
        Object instance = name.newInstance();
        Method[] methods = name.getMethods();

        for (Method method : methods) {
            if (method.getName().equals(N.getTCName())) {
                // Match found. Invoke the method. call the method on my demand.
                method.invoke(instance, null);
                break;
            }
        }
```

OR simply try this:

```
       // Get the method name at runtime
        Method method = ClassName.class.getMethod(N.getTCName(), null);
        method.invoke(new ClassName(), null);
```

Comment: Won't  FW_Report u = new FW_Report(); already load the FW_Report class?. I don;t think we need to do Class.forName(); FW_Report.class is enough.

Comment: @WhoAmI: Yes thats true. We can already load it as well.

Comment: @AnkurShanbhag: what is the point in foreach loop when you only need Clazz.getMethod(...).

Answer (score 0):

Use java reflection.

```
java.lang.reflect.Method method = u.getClass().getMethod("getReportName", param1.class, param2.class, ..);

method.invoke(obj,/*param1*/,/*param2*/,....);
```

getReportName is an example of the method name you want to call. Please refer to java reflection.